# Is OAuth2 Implicit secure?

Tags: oauth2

I have built an authorisation server using OWIN based OAuth2. I understand that the Implicit grant is basically only authenticating the redirect_URL and Client_ID when making the request. I thought, at first, this is ideal for verifying the user making the request as the Auth server will only send the code back to the one that made the request (as credentials are cross checked on a database) and as such, would not matter if the call was exposed on the **front end** as only that user could receive the token due to the redirect_URL.

Then I realised a flaw:

What if someone malicious got the call script/ajax (which I anticipated anyway) and made the call through an iframe on their page.. it wouldn't really matter that the iframe redirected and they could pull the token straight off it?

Any ideas?

**Added Code** *(sorry if its not appropriate for this channel but wanted to show you how this would be achieved)*

Bear-in-mind the "uri" has all the query parameters within.

```
// Build the query string (http://authserver.com?**client_id=11** etc)
            var uri = addQueryString(authorizeUri, {
                'client_id': '11',
                'redirect_uri': returnUri,
                'state': nonce,
                'scope': 'bio notes',
                'response_type': 'token',
            });

            console.log(uri);
            $('body').append(`<iframe src="${uri}"/>`);

            $('iframe').css({
                'display' : 'none'
            })

            $('iframe')[0].addEventListener("load", function () {
                var uriWithToken = $('iframe')[0].contentWindow.location.href;

                token = uriWithToken.split('access_token')[1].split("=")[1];
                expires = uriWithToken.split('expires_in')[1].split("=")[1];

                console.log(uriWithToken);
                console.log("TOKEN = " + token);
                console.log("EXPIRES = " + expires);
                $('iframe').remove();
            });
```

Comment: the iframe can reach it, but the top script can't pull the token from the iframe because of the SOP. you would have to load an exfiltration proxy (eg: postMessage(), 3rd-party ajax, etc) from a page on the domain containing the secret.

Comment: Hi @dandavis thanks for your response. I have added a little bit of code to show you what I mean.